# Component shows old state after action happened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

After action is happened component gets an old state anyway. I'm not mutating the state btw. The changes appears only after I refresh the page

My component **TodoList.tsx**
Here's I'm trying to get state via useEffect hook

```
export const TodoList: FC = () => {
    const {
        todoList, isLoading, isError, message
    } = useTypedSelector(
        (state) => state.todo
    )

    console.log(todoList)

    const { getTodo, reset } = useActions()

    useEffect(() => {
        getTodo()
        console.log("render")
        if (isError) {
            console.log(message)
        }
        return () => {
            reset()
        }
    }, [])

    const statusHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLParagraphElement>) => {
        const status = event.target.innerText
        if (status === "completed") {
            getTodo({ complete: true })
        } else if (status === "uncompleted") {
            getTodo({ complete: false })
        } else if (status === "all") {
            getTodo()
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    )
}
```

**my Reducer**
I'm not mutating the state also.

```
const initialState: TodoState = {
  todoList: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: ""
}

export const todoReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }: TodoAction): TodoState => {
  switch (type) {
    case "GET_TODOS":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }
    case "GET_TODOS_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, todoList: payload }
    case "GET_TODOS_ERROR":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true, message: payload.error }
    case "CREATE_TODO":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false }
    case "CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, todoList: [...state.todoList, payload]}
    case "CREATE_TODO_ERROR":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true, message: payload.error }
    case "TOGGLE_TODO":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }
    case "TOGGLE_TODO_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state, isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, todoList: state.todoList.map((todo: ITodoItem) => {
          if (todo._id === payload.id) {
            console.log(payload)
            return {
              ...todo,
              complete: !todo.complete
            }
          }
          return todo
        })
      }
    case "TOGGLE_TODO_ERROR":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true, message: payload.error }
    case "DELETE_TODO":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }
    case "DELETE_TODO_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state, isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, todoList: state.todoList.filter(
          (todo: ITodoItem) => todo._id !== payload.id
        )
      }
    case "DELETE_TODO_ERROR":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true, message: payload.error }
    case "EDIT_TODO":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }
    case "EDIT_TODO_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state, isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, todoList: state.todoList.map((todo: ITodoItem) => {
          if (todo._id === payload.id) {
            return {
              ...todo,
              text: payload.text
            }
          }
          return todo
        })
      }
    case "EDIT_TODO_ERROR":
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true, message: payload.error }
    case "RESET_TODOS":
      return { ...state, todoList: state.todoList }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**my action creator**
Here I'm making a request from my own api.

```
...
export const getTodo = (data?: GetTodos) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<TodoAction>): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: "GET_TODOS", payload: {} })
            let response
            if (data) {
                response = await todoService.getTodo((<any>data).complete)
            }
            response = await todoService.getTodo()
            console.log(response)
            dispatch({ type: "GET_TODOS_SUCCESS", payload: response })
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: "GET_TODOS_ERROR",
                payload: { error: "Cannot fetch the todos. Please try again later" }
            })
        }
    }
}

export const createTodo = (payload: CreateTodo) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<TodoAction>): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: "CREATE_TODO", payload: payload })
            const response = await todoService.createTodo(payload)
            dispatch({ type: "CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS", payload: response })
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: "CREATE_TODO_ERROR",
                payload: { error: "Cannot create todo. Please try again later" }
            })
        }
    }
}

export const toggleTodo = (payload: ToggleTodo) => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<TodoAction>): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            const response = await todoService.updateTodo(payload.id, { complete: payload.complete })
            dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_TODO_SUCCESS", payload: response })
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: "TOGGLE_TODO_ERROR",
                payload: { error: `${err}` }
            })
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

all code is here: https://github.com/maridoroshuk/todos-ts

[the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLHQW.gif)

Comment: Why are use calling an API in your action creator?

Comment: Where I have to do this? sorry, I'm currently learning...

Comment: Call your API in some other file (some sore of service file that calls the API in different functions) and simply pass the data to your action creator from the component you are calling the dispatch.

Comment: but I have a servies https://github.com/maridoroshuk/todos-ts/blob/main/frontend/src/store/servies/todo.ts

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect(callback, dependencies)` triggers **only when** data in `dependencies` changes. In your code, you put `useEffect( ... , [])`, meaning you don't have **any** dependencies, so the callback function **only runs once** when the component mounts.

If you want `useEffect` to run on every update, you need to not put any dependencies: `useEffect(...)`.

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't mention that if I add any dependencies like getTodo()/reset() , It creates infinite loop. Any ideas how I can avoid it?

Comment: So if you are **not** adding any dependency, then `useEffect` runs every render. If that is causing an infinite loop, it means you are changing something in `useEffect` that triggers a re-render. If you are adding dependencies and it causes an infinite loop, it means stuff inside `useEffect` such as `getTodo` or `reset` is causing those dependencies to change, triggering another `useEffect`.